# Rspec expected and got same but still not passing tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is the code for test:

```
it "should return the latest test result object for user" do
  value = Diagnostics.latest_test_result_object_for("urine color", @user)
  expect(value).to eq(@labtestresult3)
end
```

This is the result I am getting:

```
expected: [{"id"=>3, "lab_test_id"=>4, "user_id"=>1, "user_age"=>34, "numeric_value"=>nil, "boolean_value"=>nil, "string_value"=>"pale yellow", "lab_test_reference_label"=>nil, "lab_test_severity_level"=>nil, "lab_test_provider_id"=>1, "lab_test_method_id"=>1, "lab_test_date"=>Tue, 02 Dec 2014 16:03:33 IST +05:30, "created_at"=>Tue, 02 Dec 2014 16:03:33 IST +05:30, "updated_at"=>Tue, 02 Dec 2014 16:03:33 IST +05:30}]
     got: [{"id"=>3, "lab_test_id"=>4, "user_id"=>1, "user_age"=>34, "numeric_value"=>nil, "boolean_value"=>nil, "string_value"=>"pale yellow", "lab_test_reference_label"=>nil, "lab_test_severity_level"=>nil, "lab_test_provider_id"=>1, "lab_test_method_id"=>1, "lab_test_date"=>Tue, 02 Dec 2014 16:03:33 IST +05:30, "created_at"=>Tue, 02 Dec 2014 16:03:33 IST +05:30, "updated_at"=>Tue, 02 Dec 2014 16:03:33 IST +05:30}]

(compared using ==)

Diff:
./spec/lib/diagnostics_spec.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
-e:1:in `<main>'

1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed

Finished in 3.854677444 seconds
```

I dont understand what is the problem.

Please help.

Comment: I'd bet on a slightly different date time (milliseconds are not displayed)

Comment: @apneadiving I guess you were right, very weird coz I am using the same object on both places, I am not creating a new one, nvm I used this `expect(group_arr[0].map(&:to_s)).to eq(@labtestresult3.attributes.map(&:to_s))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your specs you are working with time, it is good practice to use gems like [`timecop`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop). In your case the problem, I assume, is with `lab_test_date`/`created_at`/`updated_at` comparison, since some time passed between action execution and expectation check. You can resolve it with `timecop` in this simple way:

```
before(:all) do
  Timecop.freeze(Time.now)
end

after(:all) do
  Timecop.return
end
```

Comment: I tried using `it "should return lab test results for a group" do
    Timecop.freeze(Time.now)
    group_arr = Diagnostics.ltr_for_group("testgroup2", @user)
    expect(group_arr).to eq([@labtestresult3.attributes])
    Timecop.return
  end` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @aelor I assume, because you defined `@labtestresult3` and `@user` before time freeze action. move freezing before any calculations.

Comment: I added the code in before(:all) and after(:all), it seems to work now . thanks !